# Forecast binary response with MATLAB glmval?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, binary-data

(I have a very similar setup to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22493759/6046501).)

`ytrain` and `Xtrain` are my training data where `ytrain` is a column of 1's and 0's and `Xtrain` is a matrix of explanatory variables. `ytrain` and `Xtrain` have the same number of rows and `Xtrain` does **not** include a column of 1's.

After doing:

```
b = glmfit(Xtrain,ytrain,'binomial')
```

I do

```
ytestfit = glmval(b,Xtest,'logit')
```

Here `Xtest` has the same number of columns as `Xtrain`. I was expecting a column of 1's and 0's for `ytestfit` (as both `ytrain` and `ytest` are columns of 1's and 0's), but instead I got a column of real numbers between 0 and 1. It seems they are probabilities so, my **guess** is that if I want to, I can add an extra step:

```
ytestfit = double(ytestfit >= 0.5)
```

> Are things above behaving as normal? Is there a way to get the
>   binary predictions directly without the additional step above?

I use MATLAB 2019b.